# Using Python requests, can I add "data" to a prepared request?

Tags: python, python-requests

The code below sets up `_request` if the HTTP method is `GET`, then it has an `if`statement for handling `PUT` `POST` and `PATCH`.

I'm trying to have one single request setup statement for all method types.

Is this possible?  It appears to me that there is no way to add `data` to a prepared request, and if this is true then perhaps I'm stuck with needing two different ways of setting up a request, one way for `GET` and one way for `PUT`, `PATCH` and `POST`.

```
def fetch_from_api(self):
        s = Session()
        headers = { "Authorization" : REST_API_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER}
        _request = Request(self.method, self.url_for_api, headers=headers)

        if self.method in ['POST', 'PATCH', 'PUT']:
            headers['content-type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            _request = Request(self.method, self.url_for_api, headers=headers, data=self.postdata)

        prepped = _request.prepare()
        self.api_response = s.send(prepped)
```

Answer (score 6):

The question is a little old and hopefully @DukeDougal already has a solution.  Maybe this will help others, though.

The first thing I notice in the example is that a `Request` object is created near the beginning of the method.  Then, if the method is "POST", "PATCH", or "PUT", the `Request` constructor is called ***again*** to get ***another*** object.  In that case, the first object is gone.  It was created unnecessarily.

When a `data=` argument isn't given to the `Request` constructor, it's the same as specifying `data=None`.  Take advantage of that and call the constructor only once, then a `data` value won't need to be added to an existing `Request` (or `PreparedRequest`) object:

```
def fetch_from_api(self):
    s = Session()
    headers = {'Authorization': REST_API_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER}
    data = None  # Assume no data until method is checked

    if self.method in ['POST', 'PATCH', 'PUT']:
        headers['content-type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        data = self.postdata  # Add the data

    # Now headers and data are ready, get a Request object
    _request = Request(self.method, self.url_for_api, headers=headers, data=data)

    prepped = _request.prepare()
    self.api_response = s.send(prepped)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the `requests.Request` [model](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L210), it looks like you can set the `data` attribute if needed:

```
some_request = Request(method, url, headers=headers)
if # ...we decide we need to add data:
    some_request.data = data
```

Looking at the model, it appears that this would work, because when you [prepare the request](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L246) later on, it looks at the instance's `data` attribute.

**EDIT**:

But reading your question a bit more closely, it looks like you want to add data to a `prepared_request`. I guess you could create your own `prepared_request` and [pass the data in specifically when you call the `prepare` method](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L246), but I don't see how that helps? It seems like you want to just branch and maybe add data or maybe not?

Anyway, the above seems it could potentially simplify your code slightly to the following:

```
 def fetch_from_api(self):
    s = Session()
    headers = { "Authorization" : REST_API_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER}
    _request = Request(self.method, self.url_for_api, headers=headers)
    if self.method in ['POST', 'PATCH', 'PUT']:
        headers['content-type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        _request.data = self.postdata
    prepped = _request.prepare()
    self.api_response = s.send(prepped)
```

(But that doesn't look much simpler to me. What are we trying to achieve? Also, it seems weird to have a method called `fetch_from_api` that could also be `POST`ing or `PUT`ing data. As a dev, I would not be expecting that to be the case from the name.)

In the past, I've done stuff like this as a result of having to sign requests: I have to create them in one place and then hand them off to a class that knows how to create signatures, which then hands them back. In other words, you can certainly edit requests before preparing and sending them on their way.

Anyway, I haven't tried any of this, but it's similar to some things I've done in the past with requests, so it looks legit, but I would be concerned about what you are attempting to achieve and whether or not things are being crammed together which maybe should not be.

Comment: I'm just wanting to use the same set of code to send a request, and try to avoid repetition. A GET request with requests varies only in the method and that is has a "data" parameter.  I thought I should be able to use a single line of code to set up the request and add "data" only if it is not a GET request.

Comment: Well, if you think about an actual HTTP request, it has `header` and a `body`.  It knows nothing about your `data`. That's why, when you look the source for `requests`  you can see a `prepared_request` after `prepare` has a `body` but no `data`. Personally, I'd probably write a function for GETs and then the other function because it seems more obvious to an outsider.

Answer (score 1):

I am using HTTPforHumans, requests module.

```
import requests

def pv_request(url, methods, data=None, headers=None, type=None):

    try:
        if 'POST' in methods:
            return requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=data).json()

        elif 'GET' in methods:
            return requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, data=data).json()

        elif 'PUT' in methods:
            if type == 'music':
                return requests.put(url=url, headers=headers, data=data).json()

            elif type == 'image':
                return requests.put(url=url, headers=headers, data=open(data, 'rb')).json()
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        return None
```

Might not be in the lines of what you are looking for, but here is my all-in-on purpose request handler.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid repetitious code in if statements.